# Android: How to know the component type in Application class?

Tags: android

I'm extending the `Application` class for my additional custom need. And I'm calling a method inside that. As the expected behaviour, it is getting invoked for type of Android components(`Activity`, `Service`, `Broadcast receiver`, etc.,) But I want that too be invoked only on `Activity`. Is that any other way to overcome this problem ?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      // the below method needs to invoked only for service
      // but now called for all application components
      myCustomMethod();
   }

   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want that too be invoked only on Activity.

Can't be done. The Application instance will run if one component of your Application is open.

You need to do the customized stuff in another class and open it just when the instance of your desire component is open.

Answer (score 2):

just add your code to onCreate method of your entry-point activity. If you want it to be called once per session - add two int keys to your shared preferences - app_launch_count and method_invoke_count. Increment first on App's onCreate and check the second in your Activity's onCreate if first greater then invoke the method :)

Comment: valid workaround. But yet not the expected solution.

Answer (score 2):

Move `myCustomMethod()` into the activity. An `Application` has no way of knowing what triggered the creation of its process.

Or, use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` on `Application` to register an `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` object, and put your `myCustomMethod()` logic in `onActivityCreated()`. This requires a `minSdkVersion` of 14 or higher. That will tell you when each activity is created after your process is instantiated — if you only care about the first one, you would have to unregister the callbacks in your `onActivityCreated()` implementation.